# Why is an electron modelled as a plane wave in the free electron model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

Why is it a plane wave, is it something that can be visualised?

Comment: It makes the math easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *free* model means that the potential is zero, if you plug in that into Schrodinger's equation you get

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\nabla^2 \Psi({\bf r},t) = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi({\bf r},t)
$$

whose solutions are of the form

$$
\Psi({\bf r},t) \sim e^{-i({\bf k}\cdot {\bf r} - \omega t)}
$$

which is a plane wave

Comment: Can this be considered to represent anything?

Comment: @Cameron It represents a electron that has not potential confining it, i.e. a free electron.

Comment: @Cameron Perhaps the question should be:  why does the free electron model work as well as it does?    After all, there are ion cores everywhere, and lots of nearby electrons ... the electrons are hardly free ...